# How in the world can you Get a CSV dump of a 10.1b Progress database?

Tags: database, csv, openedge, progress-db

I am trying to get a CSV dump from a Progress / OpenEdge 10.1b database. This was a database for Intergy EHR so the version of openEdge that shipped with the application is run-time only. I can't compile dump scripts or use Data Adminstration tool on the server to export. I've got a raw copy of all the data files / structure files. Can I extract this data with the evaluation kit version 11? Oh.. I've already contacted Progress software to try and buy a full license for 10.1b and they are just giving me the run around. Does anyone know another solution?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short of having a developer client for the program, the options I see are:

1) Connect to the 10.1B db from your 11.0 eval kit using a TCP connection, then write some code to export table CSV like so:

```
FOR EACH table-name NO-LOCK: 
   EXPORT DELIMITER "," table-name.
END.
```

2) get someone to write a CSV exporter for your 10.1B system,

3) dump all your 10.1B data, then load it into an 11.0 DB and then export from that

Comment: Thank You -- I haven't tried connecting to the 10.1 db using TCP -- that may be a workaround. I will try that.

Comment: Hi Tim -- I managed to dump all the tables to Binary Dump files -- how do I go about importing them into the v. 11 eval system?

Comment: I presume you've already made the target db. 

Look in the Database Management Database Admin docs under "proutil load" to see what's involved with a binary load.

Comment: For others dealing with a similar challenge; The proper syntax is: proutil db-name -C load filename [ -dumplist dumpfile ]

Comment: If you're dealing with Intergy (the devil's application) There is a batch file they don't want you to know about in C:\Intergy\Code\UI\Srv\DBAdmin\Support\DumpUtility\StartDump.bat -- this batch will dump every table to a binary dump file and zip them up for you.This IS THE ONLY WAY you will get this data without paying Vitera (Sage) shitloads of money to serialize your DB for ODBC or hiring them as consultants to do this for you (not cheap). It's a big racket.

Comment: I loathe companies like this almost as much as I dislike bloated enterprisey programming languages. Once you've got the binary dumps you can load them into the OpenEdge 11 evaluation kit and use Data Adminstration utility to dump to CSV -- the world is then your potato. Thanks very much for you help Tim -- you get the points.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get to the data dictionary you can export the data as text (Admin -> Export Data -> Text..).  One of the export options is to specify a delimiter.  The default is a comma.

You may need to specify the -rx or -rq client connection parameter to get to the data dictionary with a runtime license.  You get different options with the different parameters.

Comment: Thank You -- I believe I've already tried this solution. I ran this: C:\Intergy\ProRT\bin\prowin32.exe -p _admin.p -rx, which starts the Data Administration utility with more options that running it without the -rx flag. If I don't run it with the -rx flag I can't even click on the Admin menu. When I DO run the utility with the command above I can access the Admin menu, but not the export function... thoughts?

Comment: OH.. one more thing. Could you open this 10.1b database with v 10.2a? ::I feel stupid even asking this :: P.S. I did get a call from a Progress sales rep today and they are putting together a quote for me for one dev 10.1b license. What is the ballpark cost on something like this? If they have to put together a quote I'd imagine it's expensive. I still haven't received the quote.

Comment: Actually "-rx" is wrong.  Try "-rq" instead.  Q is for "Query", that option should allow you to dump the data (if you have a query license).

Comment: yep tried that and Intergy's version of OpenEdge does not have the query license. I got my quote back from Progress today too. $2700 for a single seat 10.1b developer client. Insanity! I would never pay that kind of money just to be able to get the data out of this deprecated software. Luckily I was able to binary dump everything. I'm going to proutil load into my fully featured version 11.0 evaluation kit tonight so I can do the dump to text.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the provided utility sqldump to do this.  It will dump out the table you want direct to a CSV file suffixed with .dsql. Works on all platforms. The table parameter works with wildcards so you can select to dump out all tables at once (change the PUB.ABCCode to PUB.% in example below.

In my testing this is 80% faster than using EXPORT command in 4GL code.

```
c:\program files\epicor\>sqldump -u XXXX -a XXXX -t PUB.ABCCode progress:T:l
```

ocalhost:9450:mfgsys

```
OpenEdge Release 10.2A0329  as of Thu Apr 19 10:02:30 EDT 2012

Table      : PUB.ABCCode
Dump file  : PUB.ABCCode.dsql

Dumped 10 Records, 1647 bytes, 1 seconds.

Dumped 1 Tables

c:\program files\epicor\>
```